# Pandas.astype() ValueError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to clean data from a csv file and  have got rid of the NaN values. I am sure the data types I am tring to convert (from object to float, and from object to int) do not have any NaN values, but it throws

`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'YEAR'`

```
df.dropna()
df.astype({'engine_size':'float', 'fuel_consumption_city':'float', 
           'fuel_consumption_highway':'float', 'fuel_consumption_comb1':'float', 
           'fuel_consumption_comb2':'float', 'year':'int'})
```

I'm sure there are only 'object' dtypes in the dataframe.
How do I convert from 'object' to 'float' or 'int' when this error is thrown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error tells you that you try to convert a string of letters to a number e.g `int("YEAR")`. To overcome this you of course have to make sure that your data, which you try to convert, only consists of numbers.

Try the following:

1. loop over all columns
2. try cast it to the type you want
3. when it fails, clean the column and try again